# Avoid deleting large amount of rows from a table

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-delete

I have found many q&a about how to delete large amount of data from a database or how to speed up the process but nothing about how to avoid doing that, for example:

I have a table with 10k rows (whatever the column are).
Instead of writing

```
DELETE from tableName WHERE ID=123
```

By mistake someone when writing an application forgets the where statement

```
DELETE from tableName
```

> Which will result in deleting every row from the table (I don't see
>   this an impossible scenario)

The same goes for UPDATING a row, by forgetting the WHERE clause, you will update every row from the table (which you won't even notice at first)

```
UPDATE tableName set Attribute='new_Value'
```

The previous one actually happened to me while writing a windows application (*luckily it was only a test database*)

**Now my question is, how do we avoid doing this sort of things?**

Some ideas:

1) Don't give Update and Delete permission to anyone other than sa and write SQL stored procedures/functions to update single rows

2) Check the number of rows with a trigger before update/delete

Comment: This doesn't usually get solved by technical means. Once you've had your fingers burnt once or twice by this, you tend to become more careful. Certain habits tend to form (such as writing `SELECT`s first and then transforming them into a more destructive form once the bulk of the query is written and tested, or using implicit transaction mode) and, if not learnt beforehand, it tends to focus the mind on the importance of backups *and* having recovery plans.

Comment: Hmm.. i don't get your Point. If you are writing ```DELETE FROM tablename``` you definitly want to delete all rows. How should one find out if this was by mistake. What you can do is to put e.g. a ```BEGIN TRAN``` before your Statement. Then excute your Statement and check the results. If they are OK you commit the Transaction or otherwise Rollback. There are also extensions for SSMS available (e.g. Red Gate Tools) which warn you in case of a "forgotten" where clause.

Comment: Yes I see that you didn't get my question. Well, the idea is that you have developed a database and rows are already present in the database. Someone will then create an application which interacts in the database, that someone wants to create an interaction that will delete the selected row from a list (which is also in the database), but he forgets the where clause, and he deletes all the data from that table. The idea is that there might be ideas to isolate this kind of situations (for example using stored procedure that enforces you to mention what you want to delete)

Comment: You should write your application in such a way it does not permit any user to submit everything he wants. Application form must offer to delete only the rows that are permitted to be deleted, and must ask a confirmation similar as windows asks you the confirm when you choose something to delete (file/multiple files)

Comment: it's not about how to application behaves, it is about the one who develops it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience as an information systems auditor and risk consultant, I would recommend for such situation to be resolved via building a better internal control rather than via a technical way.

We perform control assurance for large organizations during their annual audit, with one specific large topic on General IT Control. Most of those clients are public and hence data are sensitive to any potential issues/risks, and hence at the database layer:

1. we look at whether the auditee's IT team has only grant the
   needed privilege (FYI Principle of least privilege) to specific
   roles based on their job function and level of expertise - so that people who are not qualified enough will not have the opportunity to access such important data;
2. we also look at whether the developers have been granted access
   to production environment with live data where they should not - all dev jobs should be performed in a separated environment with mock data;
3. we also want to see whether the production, testing, and dev environment has been separated properly so that people will not access and update/delete
   data to a production database mistakenly where they were not meant
   to; and
4. whether a regular (a daily, weekly cold backup, or even to have a hot backup ready for switching when needed) backup of important data has been performed and properly reviewed for making sure they can easily get back to a latest point.

And being a former software engineer, I know this could be somehow troublesome but yes, "I don't see this an impossible scenario".

Comment: I would add for the backup scenario consider the use of transactional backups, so a restore can be made just before an accident. Without any data-loss, this mainly depends of the risk factor to regenerate the amount of data lost from last backup to incident time (which is called RPO).